# Unable to call function in php require file

Tags: php, function

I'm missing something really simple here!

index.php requires connect.php:

```
<?php require_once('scripts/connect.php'); ?>
```

connect.php collects some data from a DB and places it in an array:

```
<? $query = "SELECT id,termine FROM tbl_standorte";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("no query");
$result_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){$termine_array[] = $row;} ?>
```

index.php then requires sub.php:

```
<? require('sub.php');?>
```

And sub.php contains the following function which is then called by passing a variable to $value:

```
<? function searchSubArray($value) {
        foreach ($termine_array as $subarray){  
        if (isset($subarray['id']) && $subarray['id'] == $value)
          echo 'Result:'.str_replace(';','&lt;br&gt;',$subarray['termine']);       
        }
} ?>
```

sub.php then calls the function `<p><? searchSubArray(133);?></p>`

However, I get no output! What am I missing?

Comment: Check if your echo statement has been reached.

Comment: `$termine_array` is not defined within that function

Comment: where you defined `$termine_array` varable?

Comment: Sorry guys. Forgot to mention that the array is filled with the connect.php file.

Comment: You're still not accessing `$termine_array` as a global within that function (assuming that's what's you're intending to do, even though using globals is often frowned upon).  See the output of [this quick example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/13a1fe8eb95ddaae749c62f4738c80cf0084fe96). Unlike in Javascript, just defining the variable outside of a function does not automatically give you global access to it within the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is likely just adding

```
global $termine_array;
```

before your `foreach` statement as such

```
<? function searchSubArray($value) {
    global $termine_array;
    foreach ($termine_array as $subarray){  
    ...
```

However, I'd strongly recommend that you consider re-writing this from the ground up.  Start by replacing your usage of the deprecated `mysql_*` functions with either [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  Then, I'd see if you can replace your use of global variables with objects.  Maybe have a `standorte.php` class that contains a `getAllIDs()` function.

I'd suggest looking into some MVC frameworks, as the code that you have here seems like it could really use it. `index.php` is trying to be a controller, `connect.php` is trying to be a model, and `sub.php` is trying to be a view.